# Do all polynomials $p(x)$ with integer coefficients output infinitely many composite numbers for integer $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732226/fake-proof-that-the-difference-of-two-consecutive-cubes-is-prime/4732276#4732276), I was wondering if there was a simple proof that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ and with integer coefficients, then $p(x)$ is a composite number for infinitely many integers $x.$

We can split it into reducible and irreducible polynomials over either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't see how that helps actually.

This [paper](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eflemmermeyer/publ/composite.pdf) seems relevant, but to me it is not so simple to understand (for example I am not super familiar with [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials))) and I wonder if a simpler solution exists. Maybe the fact that I am not familiar with Gauss' Lemma means I should not be asking this question? If this is the feedback, then so be it.

Comment: Almost surely this is the case , otherwise we would have a polynomial $p(n)$ being prime for EVERY sufficient large integer $n$ , extremely hard to imagine. But it is probybla nevertheless an open problem.